# Rails upload to s3 performance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, upload, amazon-s3

I'm building an app to store files on my s3 account. I use Rails 3.0.0beta

A lot of files can be uploaded at the same time, and the cost (from a performance point of view) of an upload is quite heavy, my app will be busy handling uploads all the time!

Maybe a solution is to upload directly to s3, but I still need a submit to my app, at least to store the file's name.

I'm wondering what is the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the time consuming operation asynchronously in the background with a solution like [delayed job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job). [Compatibility](http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/search?search=delayed&commit=Search).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 3, please check out my sample projects which allow you to upload directly to S3 and offload the work from the app.  Then you can just use delayed job to do secondary operations:

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash and MooTools-based FancyUploader to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload